# How to list wordpress attachment urls with commas?

Tags: wordpress

I have an image gallery field on my posts where I can add multiple images.

I need to list attachment urls in commas inside `data-thumb"url1,url2,url3"` How can I separate thumbs in commas in the below function?

```
function multi_thumbs_array(){
    global $post;
        $images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'images', true );
      if( $images ):
        $size = 'thumbnail';
            foreach( $images as $image ):
              echo wp_get_attachment_image_url($image, $size);
            endforeach;
      endif;
 }
```

Tried also this:

```
function multi_thumbs_array(){
    global $post;
        $images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'images', true );
      if( $images ) {
        $size = 'thumbnail';
            foreach( $images as $image ) {
              $thumbs = wp_get_attachment_image_url($image, $size);
         }
     }
     if( is_array($thumbs) ){
        return implode(',', $thumbs);
    }

    return false;
 }
```

The code above is working but its listing urls without any comma.I have tried to use `multi_thumbs_array()` in implode but it when i do that it doesn't work.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your code a little. F.e. $thumbs  should be an array, not a string.

```
function multi_thumbs_array(){
    global $post;
    $thumbs=array();
    $images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'images', true );

    if( $images ) {
        $size = 'thumbnail';

        foreach( $images as $image ) {
            $thumbs[] = wp_get_attachment_image_url($image, $size);
        }
    } else {
        $get_first_image=get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );    
        $get_first_image=array_shift( array_values($get_first_image) );
        $thumbs_arr = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $get_first_image->ID );
        $thumbs[] = $thumbs_arr[0];
    }

    /* no need to check if $thumbs is array as it is 
       declared in array and it's type doesn't get modified in the code */

    return implode(',', $thumbs); //returns empty string if $thumbs is empty
}
```

Comment: Great Elvin thankyou so much just one question is there any way to dedect if there is only one image or multiple images something like `if ( count($images) > 1 )` your answer is just the solution for this answer but Im asking this because when I have only one image attached I get a blank div. So I mean to make the first image a default image.

Comment: If $images returns array or just one single image data, then my code would work for it. if $images returns empty data, then you need to add ELSE part to you if ($images)  condition.  i am adding sample to my code, check my answer again

Comment: Thankyou Elvin everything is working fine thankyou very much.